# How to calculate the Lie algebra of a neural network?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, neural-networks

Define $F$ as the standard multi-layer feed-forward perceptron:
\begin{equation}
F(\mathbf{x}) = \Theta( W_1 \circ \Theta( W_2 \circ .... W_L(\mathbf{x})))
\end{equation}
where $\Theta$ is the sigmoid function and $W_\ell$ is the weight matrix for layer $\ell$, every layer contains $N$ neurons, with a total of $L$ layers.

$x \in X$ is a vector space of dimension $N$.

$F$ forms a group acting on $X$.

$F$ can be parameterized by the $N \times N$ weight matrices $W_\ell$ (there are $L$ of them).  The total number of parameters is $L \cdot N^2$.  In other words, $F$ is parameterized by $W \in \mathbb{R}^{L N^2}$.

How can I calculate the explicit elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \mbox{Lie } F$?

The sigmoid function can be either:
$$\Theta(\xi) = \frac{1}{1+ e^{-a \xi}} \quad \mbox{(logistic)}$$
$$\Theta(\xi) = \tanh(\xi)$$
$$\Theta(\xi) = \begin{cases}
    0,              & \xi < 0 \\
    \xi,            & \xi \geq 0
\end{cases} \quad \mbox{(rectifier)}$$
(choose whichever one leads to an elegant solution).

I'm just beginning to learn Lie theory, and would like to apply it to neural network research.  Thanks.

Comment: This could use some clarification - you seem to be conflating a single transformation $F$ (as you defined it) with the group of all such transformations. What are the allowed values of the $W_\ell$? You certainly need at least invertibility if you want these transformations to form a group. How does the function $\Theta : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ act on $X$? Componentwise after fixing a basis? Also $F \in \mathbb R^{L N^2}$ does not mean what you intend.

Comment: Thanks, $\Theta$ acts componentwise.  F(W) for all possible W's form the "group", but it may not be a group.  Is it even likely that these F's could form a group?

Comment: Oh, F(W)'s do not form a group, because $F^{-1}$ cannot be expressed in the above form.  (All the sigmoid functions I showed are not self-inverses).

Comment: Technically you don't need $\Theta$ to be self-inverse, but it certainly needs to be invertible, and no composition of matrices and $\tanh$ is going to give you $\tanh^{-1}$. The first thing to check is the presence of an identity transformation, which I think might already force $\Theta$ to be linear. Certainly does in the case $L=1$.

Comment: If you allow approximations, then it is possible to have identity and inverses.  Otherwise, these F's can never form a group.

Comment: @YanKingYin Can you tell me which textbooks you're using to learn this material? Any recommendations?

Comment: But the question can be continued if I define another class of $F^{-1}$'s with $\Theta^{-1}$ replacing $\Theta$.  And then I drop in the identity elements.  That would be a group, right?

Comment: Oh, then it's still not a connected manifold... :(

Comment: It seems that for the elements to form a smooth manifold, we need to include infinitely many layers, but then Lie theory requires the manifold to be of finite dimensions.

Comment: Either L or N would have to go to infinity or else the approximations near the identity element would have finite non-zero errors.

Comment: There is still a remedy, which is to parameterize the sigmoid function as well, such that it can become the identity function x=y.  Then I guess we have a Lie group and the question can be continued :)

Comment: The logistic function with $a = \infty$ becomes identity.  So we have $L N^2 + 1$ parameters.

Comment: If $\Theta(\xi) = \xi$ then $L$ doesn't matter, since the product of two matrices is a matrix. You'd just get $GL(N)$ (assuming you require invertibility of $W$).

Comment: The last hope may be to use the rectifier function....

Comment: littleO:  I may include some background references after this discussion :)

Comment: The rectifier "_/" $\Theta$ and its inverse $\Theta^{-1}$ and its negation ($\Theta(-Id)$) form a 3-element basis of an algebra.  The question is whether it is different from GL(N).

Comment: Oh, it's the same problem as before... it becomes GL(N).

Comment: Wait a minute... even if the group contains GL(X), some group elements are not linear so the group is not the same as GL(X).

Comment: littleO:  "Matrix groups for undergraduates" may be a nice and gentle introduction.